# I want to know why this function return True and False not 1 and 0 (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

When i input True, or False in function 'my_abs()' I want the result to print `1` or `0` but this function returns `True` and `False`.

```
def my_abs (a):
    if isinstance(a,int) or isinstance(a,float):
        if a>=0:
            b=a     
        else:
            b=-a
    elif isinstance(a, bool):
        if a == True:
            b="1"
        else:
            b="0"
    elif isinstance(a, complex):
        r=a.real
        i=a.imag
        b=((r**2)+(i**2))**(0.5)
    else:
        b="only a number can be handled!"
    return b


print(my_abs(True))
print(my_abs(False))
```

Comment: Bools are ints in Python.

Comment: Try `isinstance(True, int)`

Comment: Try to put the second elif in the place of your first if (bool) <-> (int, float). Because a boolean is an integer but an integer is not always a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Since `isinstance(True, int)` is True, you will enter the first part of your if-test when you pass a bool as an argument. To get your desired result, try changing the order of how you test for types:

```
def my_abs(a):
    if isinstance(a, bool):
        if a == True:
            b = "1"
        else:
            b = "0"
    elif isinstance(a, int) or isinstance(a, float):
        if a >= 0:
            b = a
        else:
            b = -a
    elif isinstance(a, complex):
        r = a.real
        i = a.imag
        b = ((r ** 2) + (i ** 2)) ** (0.5)
    else:
        b = "only a number can be handled!"
    return b

print(my_abs(True))
print(my_abs(False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Booleans in Python are implemented as a subclass of integers so that's why your first block of code **(which is an integer)** is executing.

So to fix it you have to rearrange your code to handle this behavior.

```
def my_abs(a):
    if isinstance(a, bool):
        if a:
            b = "1"
        else:
            b = "0"
    elif isinstance(a, int) or isinstance(a, float):
        if a >= 0:
            b = a
        else:
            b = -a
    elif isinstance(a, complex):
        r = a.real
        i = a.imag
        b = ((r ** 2) + (i ** 2)) ** (0.5)
    else:
        b = "only a number can be handled!"
    return b


print(my_abs(True))
print(my_abs(False))
```

Thanks :)

Comment: No type casting is occurring here. The `bool` value `True` *is* an `int` object without needing to be cast. That's because `bool` is a subclass of `int`. You can see the same thing with your own classes, e.g. given `class A: pass` and `class B(A): pass`, `isinstance(B(), A)` will return `True`.